# Pass variable from input to GraphQL search call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, react-apollo

I am in the process of learning graphql and react-apollo. I have set up a search query in my code. I am unsure how to pass a variable from my code (i.e. `this.state.search`) to my grapnql call.

I have looked at many answers including [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45245182/how-to-pass-variable-to-graphql-from-method-when-onclick-with-button-and-get-it), but it seems a bit different.

[The docs also don't seem](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/basics/queries.html#graphql-query-data-variables) to give any guidance on how to use state as the variable.

My code is below.

Can anyone advise how to connect both of these?

```
import React, { Component} from 'react'
import { graphql } from 'react-apollo'
import gql from 'graphql-tag'

class Search extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      search: ''
    }
  }

  updateSearch = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      search: e.target.value
    })
  }

  submitSearch = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    console.log(this.state)
  }

  render() {

    const { search } = this.state;

    return (
      <form onSubmit={ this.submitSearch }>
        <input 
          type='text'
          onChange={ this.updateSearch }
          value={ search }
          placeholder='Search'    
        />
      </form>
    )
  }
}


export default graphql(gql`
{
  search(query: "Manchester", type: TEAM) {
    name
  }
}`)(Search)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll want to split this up into at least two components. One that holds the state of what the user searched, then another that actually does the querying by getting a prop. Additionally you can have the apollo higher order component skip the query if the form was submitted without entering something.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import {graphql} from 'react-apollo'
import gql from 'graphql-tag'

class Results extends Component {
   render() {
    // apollo provides results under the data prop
    const {data} = this.props;
    return <h1>{data.search.namej}</h1>
   }
}

const ResultsWithQuery = graphql(gql`
query FindTeam($query: String!) {
    search(query: $query, type: TEAM) {
        name
    }
}
`, {skip: (ownProps) => !ownProps.query})(Results);

export class Search extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        search: ''
    }
}

updateSearch = (e) => {
    this.setState({
        search: e.target.value
    })
}

submitSearch = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    console.log(this.state)
}

render() {

    const {search} = this.state;

    return (
        <div>

        <form onSubmit={this.submitSearch}>
            <input
                type='text'
                onChange={this.updateSearch}
                value={search}
                placeholder='Search'
            />
            <ResultsWithQuery query={search} />
        </form>
        </div>

    )
}
}
```

*** UPDATE ***
Now that react-apollo@2.1 has been released there is an alternative way using render props.

https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/essentials/get-started.html#request

This simplifies the number of components you need in this case.

```
import React, { Component} from 'react'
import { Query } from 'react-apollo'
import gql from 'graphql-tag'

const SearchQuery = gql`
query FindTeam($query: String!) {
  search(query: $query, type: TEAM) {
    name
  }
}
`;

export default class Search extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        search: ''
    }
}

updateSearch = (e) => {
    this.setState({
        search: e.target.value
    })
}

submitSearch = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    console.log(this.state)
}

render() {

    const { search } = this.state;

    return (
        <form onSubmit={ this.submitSearch }>
            <input
                type='text'
                onChange={ this.updateSearch }
                value={ search }
                placeholder='Search'
            />
            <Query query={SearchQuery} skip={!search} variables={{query: search}}>
               {({loading, error, data}) => {
                    if (loading) return null;
                    if (error) throw err;
                   return <h1>{data.search.namej}</h1>
                }}
            </Query>
        </form>
    )
}
}
```

Comment: is this the only way to do this?

Comment: Passing a prop as the query param into the apollo higher order component? Yes that is the only way to write a dynamic query based on user input. *How* you pass the prop (using redux, context whatever) is up to you.

Comment: thanks for the answer, it kind of seems like overkill that you would have to create an extra component for this